# hide rows of named ranges when they are empty in column

Tags: excel, vba

hope you can help me with my excel-vba-problem, please!

trying to hide some rows if the 5th column is empty.

[i have a picture included:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h32yJ.png)

i have three named ranges called "SOMCT", "MMSE" and "MOCA"

e.g. named range "SOMCT" spans from A3:E4
MMSE from A5:E6
MOCA from A7:E8

if the 5th column within one range is empty the whole rows of that range should be hidden. otherwise the cells should be shown.

as in the picture: only the last 2 rows (with the named range "MOCA" - A7 and A8) should be shown, all the other rows of named ranges "SOMCT" and "MMSE" should be hidden.

i'd like to implement this with a button-click.

thanks in advance!

regards, stephan

Comment: Typically here you're expected to show your efforts to resolve your own problem before asking for help.  What *specifically* is preventing you from getting this done?

Comment: sry, i'm new to this. tried lots of things and don't think i'm on the right path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim r, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each r In Array("SOMCT", "MMSE", "MOCA") 'array of range names
        With ws.Range(r)
            .EntireRow.Hidden = .Parent.Evaluate( _
                        "=SUM(1*(" & .Columns(5).Address & "<>""""))") = 0
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer and help! brilliant! but it doesnt work with cells that have a formula behind it and don't show a text. if i manually write something in the cell it works. is there please any way i can make this work if the cells are empty ("") and have a formula in it? like this: =IF(C95="";"";IF(C95<7;"unauffällig";"auffällig"))...or maybe its just easier if i check the opposite: if cells have visible text in it...

Comment: I can take a look later…

Comment: See edit - that worked for me when cells contained a formula but the formula was not returning any content.

Comment: doesnt work with my file. doesnt hide anything right now.

Comment: Oops I missed the `.Columns(5)` from the `Evaluate` - worked for me as I only had content in the last column when I tested.